# how do I log error on creating, updating and deleting in elequont

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am using a Class BaseModel which extends Elequont. So this BaseModel is inherited by every model in my app. Now what I want to do is that whenever in any model if there is any insert ,update or select is running and any error occured so I want to log that error with class name (Model name) , function name and parameters.
   Is this possible with laravel 4?? if so, then how ?

Any help would be appreciated . Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Since Laravel is pretty flexibile it is possible to do that in more than one way.
You can create your own exception class by extending laravel native exception, and define your rules. Next, you can listen for that exception with your custom event:

```
Event::listen("your_event","action");
Event::fire("your_event");
```

Now place your event trigger in some visible place for your app. **app/start/global.php.** file is a good place, since it is application specific.

Also there is Laravel App::error class, which is basic framowork error handler:

```
App::error(function(Exception $exception)
{
    Log::error($exception);
});
```

Laravel logging functionality is provided by **Monolog**.